# display structure by using single image - optimization

Tags: html

I have to use the following structure in my client wbesite

[image]

I have done it using an image. This display come in many places and each will have different descriptions. So I use a separate image for each.

Is it possible to use it using HTML, without using a separate image for each? Say, by using the same image and provide option to change descriptions?

I have partially achieved this. How I have done is using a table structure and using the following background image for the table.

[image]

This works fine, but the aliment is not perfect as the length of description changes. Is there a better approach for this (preferably not using js). please advise

Comment: This seems like a great application for SVG.